# Realm query with IN operator slow

Tags: swift, database, performance, realm

Could I get some help with these Realm queries.

Database has over 400K records, both 'length' and 'key' are indexed.

When filtering using the following query (note the IN containment part has about 40,000 random-unique(no-duplicates) elements, the query takes **over 25seconds**

```
let predX = "length == 8 AND key IN {"acdghikl", "abfjlnop", "adefilno", ... " }
```

However, when I OR-combine that same query with other queries that have records that are completely independent from each other the fetching takes a lot less, **under 5 seconds.**. The set of records of length6 is disjoint from set of records of length7 and disjoint from set of records of length8

```
let predX = "length == 6 AND key IN {"uadhet", "nvawrt", "aqswdf", ... " }
let predY = "length == 7 AND key IN {"lmnzxiu", "bcruajs", "rokjuhy", ... " }
let predZ = "length == 8 AND key IN {"acdghikl", "abfjlnop", "adefilno", ... " }
let predCombined = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predX, predY, predZ])
```

*Update-Edit:*

For clarification, my current solution is to simply fetch the records by length only, which takes less than 0.05s, add all the 'keys' to a Set, and check if the set contains the key. The total time averages to **under 0.45secs**, but if I use the complete query Realm with IN takes **over 25secs**

1) Complete query with IN operator: over 25secs

```
// about 40K keys in the IN containment
let predX = "length == 8 AND key IN {"acdghikl", "abfjlnop", "adefilno", ... " } " 
let result = realm.objects(XXX.self).filter(predX)
// result.count = 578
```

2) Query without IN operator (0.05s) and filtering records outside of Realm (~0.4s): Total under 0.45secs

```
let predX = "length == 8"
let result = realm.objects(XXX.self).filter(predX)
var filtered = [String]()
for record in result { // Over 50K records fetched
  if setOfKeys.contains(record.key) {
    filtered.append(record.key)
  }
}
// filtered.count = 578
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` in Realm is not particularly clever or optimized. Internally, `x IN arr` is translated to `x == arr[0] OR x == arr[1] OR ...`. This gives `O(N*M)` runtime, where `N` is the number of objects and `M` is the number of values in the `IN` clause. By comparison, the manual filtering with `setOfKeys` (assuming that is a `Set<String>`) gives `O(N)` or `O(N log M)` runtime, which will be much faster for large `M`.

It's not obvious to me why OR-combining queries with disjoint sets would make things faster.

Comment: Indeed `It's not obvious to me why OR-combining queries with disjoint sets would make things faster.` is what I am mostly wondering. The records I am filtering by OR-combine are completely different, yet by OR combining the queries the time is reduced drastically compared to querying one by one.